# Cookies Audit help

Tags: cookie

Someone can explain to me what is the purpose of these cookies? I'm doing a cookies audit and I didn't find anything on the web

- Domain: google.com(google maps), Name: NID
- Domain: google.com(google maps), Name: SNID
- Domain: google.com(google maps), Name: khcookie
- Domain: google.com(google maps), Name: PREF

---

- Domain: tripadvisor.com, Name: ServerPool
- Domain: tripadvisor.com, Name: TAReturnTo
- Domain: tripadvisor.com, Name: TAUnique
- Domain: tripadvisor.com, Name: v1st